# Send data from Droidscript to ESP32

Tags: esp32, droidscript

I am trying to create an android app using Droidscript in order to send some data to an ESP32.

Searching on the web I found several ways to do it but all of them are quite complicated.

Can anyone help me how to continue from now on ???

Thanks a lot !!

Comment: Hi @kkdoughnut, welcome to Stack Overflow. Trying to use one of the quite complicated ways to do it that you found and asking a question about the trouble you run into is more likely to get you help than asking a very general question like this or asking for recommendations.

Comment: what kind of data you want to send? Text/commands, Images, Sound?
What communication way you want to use? Wifi, Bluetooth, Serial?